# unable to pass password to su

Tags: linux, apache, bash, ssh, su

I have a bash script that requires a couple commands be run under a different user.  I would like to do this with su but I am unable to automatically su without a password prompt.

The user running the script will be apache in centos (so not a real user account, e.g you cannot do su apache and get a prompt under apache user).

Thus, I dont think something like expect will work.  I also can't ssh from apache to another localhost account using ssh keys.

Is there a way to accomplish my objective? Hardcoding passwords is acceptable to me.

Comment: you can use sudo and allow apache to passwordless execute some files as a different user

Answer (score 3):

This is what `sudo` was built for - fine grained permission raising. If you add the script as something apache can run with sudo (in the `/etc/sudoers` file), you can provide limited permission escalation.

However, requiring anything invoked from the apache user is very very dangerous. It could quickly turn a limited local exploit into a root exploit. Be very careful in sanitizing your input, understand how shells expand variables, etc.